# While Scrolling RecyclerView, custom-view value keep changing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have issue that when I click to increase quantity of position first item and when I scolling down and up then, position of that item is flickering...

Please help me out guys thanks in advance

This is my adapter class.

```
package growcia.malacus.com.growcia.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

 import java.util.List;

 import growcia.malacus.com.growcia.R;
 import growcia.malacus.com.growcia.activity.ProductListActivity;
 import growcia.malacus.com.growcia.database.SqliteDatabaseClass;
 import growcia.malacus.com.growcia.model.SellerProductPOJO;



 public class ProductListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public Context context;
SqliteDatabaseClass DB;
String productCode;
boolean isPressed = false;
int count = 0;
int qty;


public String pname, price, img_path;
static int productItem = 0;
int totPrice;

ProductListActivity objProductList;
List<SellerProductPOJO> productListDetails;


public ProductListAdapter(List<SellerProductPOJO> productDetails, Context context) {
    super();

    DB = new SqliteDatabaseClass(context);
    objProductList = new ProductListActivity();
    this.productListDetails = productDetails;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final SellerProductPOJO objSellerProductPOJO = productListDetails.get(position);

    try {
        JSONArray jar = DB.getAllProductCodeAndQtyProductList();
        Log.e("total pid and qty ad : ", "" + jar.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < jar.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject job = jar.getJSONObject(i);

            String cart_productId = job.getString("ProductCode");
            String productQty = job.getString("QuantityOrdered");

            Log.e("id and qty: ", cart_productId + " qty: " + productQty);

            String plist_prod_id = productListDetails.get(position).getProductCode();

            Log.e("product id in cart : ", "" + cart_productId.toString());
            Log.e("product id service : ", "" + plist_prod_id.toString());

        }

    } catch (JSONException J) {
        J.printStackTrace();
    }


    String url = objSellerProductPOJO.getImagePath();
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   // optional
            .error(R.drawable.error)   // optional
            .resize(100, 100)                        // optional
            .into(holder.ivProduct);
    holder.tvProductName.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getProductName());
    holder.tvUnit.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getAvailableQuantity());
    holder.tvPrice.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getPrice());

    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/abc.ttf");
    holder.tvProductName.setTypeface(font);
    holder.tvUnit.setTypeface(font);
    holder.tvPrice.setTypeface(font);


    if (context instanceof ProductListActivity)
        totPrice = DB.getSumPrice();
    Log.e("all price insert : ", "" + totPrice);
    count = DB.getProfilesCount();
    Log.e("count from db", "" + count);
    ((ProductListActivity) context).showCartItem(count, totPrice);



    holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SellerProductPOJO objSellerProduct = productListDetails.get(position);


            String stock = holder.tvUnit.getText().toString();
            int qtyMiddle = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvQty.getText().toString());
            int qtyStock = Integer.parseInt(objSellerProduct.getAvailableQuantity().toString());


            if (!stock.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                if (qtyMiddle < qtyStock) {


                    pname = objSellerProduct.getProductName();
                    img_path = objSellerProduct.getImagePath();
                    price = objSellerProduct.getPrice();
                    productCode = objSellerProduct.getProductCode();


                    String str_qty = holder.tvQty.getText().toString();
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(str_qty);

                    qty = qty + 1;
                    String final_str_qty = "" + qty;


                    objSellerProductPOJO.setQty(final_str_qty);
                    holder.tvQty.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getQty() + "");

                    int reduceable_stock = qtyStock - qty;

                    holder.tvUnit.setText(reduceable_stock + "");

                    if (qty > 0) {
                        boolean entryStatus = DB.Exists(productCode);
                        if (entryStatus) {

                            productItem = productItem + 1;
                            String str_newQty = holder.tvQty.getText().toString();
                            int newqty = Integer.parseInt(str_newQty);
                            double intPrice = Double.parseDouble(price);
                            double totPrice = qty * intPrice;
                            DB.updateProductQty(productCode, newqty, totPrice);
                            totPrice = DB.getSumPrice();
                            Log.e("all price update: ", "" + totPrice);

                        } else {
                            productItem = 1;
                            DB.addProductItem(productCode, pname, img_path, productItem, price, price);

                        }
                        if (context instanceof ProductListActivity)
                            totPrice = DB.getSumPrice();
                        Log.e("all price insert : ", "" + totPrice);
                        count = DB.getProfilesCount();
                        Log.e("count from db", "" + count);
                        ((ProductListActivity) context).showCartItem(count, totPrice);
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Product out of stock!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        }
    });

    holder.btnMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String stock = holder.tvUnit.getText().toString();
            if (!stock.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                SellerProductPOJO objSellerProductDeduct = productListDetails.get(position);

                String str_qty = holder.tvQty.getText().toString();
                int qty = Integer.parseInt(str_qty);

                if (qty != 0) {

                    int qtyStockMinusClick = Integer.parseInt(holder.tvUnit.getText().toString());

                    holder.tvUnit.setText((qtyStockMinusClick + 1) + "");



                    Log.e("btnMinus", "" + qty);

                    if (qty == 1) {
                        Log.e("", "inside 0 qty");
                        DB.delete_byID(productCode);
                        qty = qty - 1;
                        String final_str_qty = "" + qty;

                        objSellerProductPOJO.setQty(final_str_qty);
                        holder.tvQty.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getQty()+"");


                    } else {

                        qty = qty - 1;
                        String final_str_qty = "" + qty;

                        objSellerProductPOJO.setQty(final_str_qty);
                        holder.tvQty.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getQty()+"");


                        double intPrice = Double.parseDouble(price);
                        double totPrice = qty * intPrice;

                        DB.updateProductQty(productCode, qty, totPrice);
                    }

                    if (context instanceof ProductListActivity)
                        totPrice = DB.getSumPrice();
                    Log.e("all price insert : ", "" + totPrice);
                    count = DB.getProfilesCount();
                    Log.e("count from db", "" + count);
                    ((ProductListActivity) context).showCartItem(count, totPrice);

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Product out of stock!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });


    holder.imagefavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.e("position", "all position" + position);
            if (isPressed)
                holder.imagefavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_not_favourite);
            else
                holder.imagefavorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.favourite_icon);

            isPressed = !isPressed;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productListDetails.size();
}



class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvProductName;
    public TextView tvUnit;
    public TextView tvPrice;
    public TextView tvQty;
    public ImageView ivProduct;
    public ImageView imagefavorite;
    //  public EditText edqntiry;
    public Button btnPlus;
    public Button btnMinus;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivProduct = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProduct);
        tvProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
        tvUnit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUnit);
        tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
        tvQty = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvQty);
        btnPlus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlus);
        btnMinus = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnMinus);
        imagefavorite = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagefavorite);
    }

}
}
```

When I am going to incerase qty then below screen shows

[image]

when I am scrolled down and up then below screen shows

[image]

Comment: What do you mean *position of that item is flicurring*?

Comment: see the above two images...

Comment: 1st image is before scrolling and next is after scrolling

Comment: This is a simple case where `RecyclerView` reuses the `View`s  it created (ScrappedViews). So just rebinding your data to the `holder.tvQty` will fix the issue. As suggested by @user6709464. I'd also encourage you not to add/create new listeners in `onBindView()` (A new instance will be created each time you scroll into a new view). Put them in ViewHolder.

Comment: I have updated the same..

Comment: That means I have to  put clicked listener into view holder??

Comment: Yes you will have to put the click listener in `ViewHolder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the initial value of holder.tvQty in your onBindViewHolder method.

When you update the value of holder.tvQty in holder.btnPlus or holder.btnMinus listeners, you should save that value somewhere in your objSellerProductPOJO:

```
objSellerProductPOJO.setQty(final_str_qty)
```

Then under:

```
holder.tvPrice.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getPrice());
```

add:

```
holder.tvQty.setText(objSellerProductPOJO.getQty());
```

Comment: Welcome.. Can you update your question with what you tried?

Comment: Ok Thank You. Can you tell me how to initialze.? please

Comment: holder.tvQty.setText("insert saved value");

Comment: Thanks  Elias N... I have initialize qty in the class from where I want to getQty().

Comment: @ Elias N. I have the same question. But cant apply this solution . [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/67245065/14253444)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the productListDetails variable on add or subtract after

holder.tvQty.setText(final_str_qty);

And notify the adapter using notifydatasetchange()

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick() methods, replace the the *position* parameter of the onBindViewHolder() method with the *getAdapterPosition()*.

Replace from

```
SellerProductPOJO objSellerProduct = productListDetails.get(position);
SellerProductPOJO objSellerProductDeduct = productListDetails.get(position);
```

to

```
SellerProductPOJO objSellerProduct = productListDetails.get(getAdapterPosition());
SellerProductPOJO objSellerProductDeduct = productListDetails.get(getAdapterPosition());
```