# Cannot get sum of values from firebase Realtime properly outside the recycler view

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am making an android app based on firebase Realtime. I am able to get **sum** of child nodes in my recycler view. But I also need the grand total of those **SUM values** outside the recycler view. The required **Grand Total** is available but is not exact (true). Furthermore, the Grand Total is not correct until we scroll to the bottom. It also keeps changing when we scroll the recycler view up and down.
This is the code of my activity:--

```
 myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(time + "ExpanseBudget");
//-------------------------
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<category>()
                .setQuery(myRef, category.class)
                .build();
        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<category, holder1> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<category, holder1>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull holder1 holder, final int i, @NonNull @NotNull category model) {

                final String title = getRef(i).getKey();

                assert title != null;
                holder.btnHistory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent o;
                        o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class);
                        o.putExtra("Title", title);
                        o.putExtra("Type", "Expanse");
                        startActivity(o);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                holder.btnEntry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent o;

                        o = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EntryActivity.class);
                        o.putExtra("Title", title);
                        o.putExtra("Type", "Expanse");

                        startActivity(o);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                final int[] spent = {0};
                myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(time + "ExpanseBudget");
                myRef.child(title).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int budget = 0;

                        if (dataSnapshot.getValue() == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {


                            final String stData1 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData1").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData2 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData2").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData3 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData3").getValue())).toString();
                            final String stData4 = (Objects.requireNonNull(dataSnapshot.child("stData4").getValue())).toString();


                            category basic = new category(stData1, stData2, stData3, stData4);
                            holder.tvCategory.setText(stData3);
                            holder.tvBudget.setText("@" + stData4);
                            int amount = 0;

                            //important line
                            try {
                                amount = (Integer.parseInt(stData4));
                            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                            }
                            //======================
                            budget = amount;

                            myRef = myfire.getReference().child("Data").child(strUID).child(time + "ExpanseEntry" + title);
                            final int finalBudget = budget;
                            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                int sum = 0;
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        String value = data.child("stData4").getValue(String.class);
                                        assert value != null;
                                        int total = 0;

                                        //important line
                                        try {
                                            total = (Integer.parseInt(value));
                                        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                        }
                                        //======================
                                        sum = sum + total;
                                    }

                                    holder.tvAmount.setText("(-)" + String.valueOf(sum)  );
                                    holder.tvBalance.setText("(=)" + String.valueOf(finalBudget - sum) );

                                    //important line
                                    try {
                                        totalSpent = (totalSpent + sum);
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                    }
                                    //======================
                                    try {
                                        totalSaved = (totalEarned - totalSpent);
                                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                                    }

                                    tvAmountB.setText("(-)"+String.valueOf(totalSpent));
                                    tvBalanceB.setText("(=)"+String.valueOf(totalSaved));
                                }


                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                    throw databaseError.toException(); // never ignore errors
                                }
                            });

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                        throw error.toException(); // never ignore errors
                    }

                });
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public holder1 onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item1, parent, false);
                return new holder1(v);
            }
        };
//==============================adapter===============================


      //===============================================================================================

        userlist.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.startListening();

    }

}
```

In short, I want:-
1-Grand total outside the recycler view without scrolling to the bottom.
2-The grand total should not change on scrolling up and down.

Please correct me with an example.

*Edit*
I found that when scrolling down it adds the last child value. And when scrolling up it adds the value of the first child.

My json file

```
{
  "Data" : {
    "UyhzVqsz1BVFKoePa2NEmlPFu382" : {
      "May:2021ExpanseBudget" : {
        "Clothes" : {
          "stData1" : "May:2021",
          "stData2" : "Expanse",
          "stData3" : "Clothes",
          "stData4" : "5000"
        },
        "Xtra" : {
          "stData1" : "May:2021",
          "stData2" : "Expanse",
          "stData3" : "Xtra",
          "stData4" : "4000"
        }
      },
      "May:2021ExpanseEntryClothes" : {
        "-M_2ascI0SYDI5O23V1R" : {
          "stData1" : "Clothes",
          "stData2" : "7 May 2021",
          "stData3" : "dress",
          "stData4" : "1000"
        }
      },
      "May:2021ExpanseEntryXtra" : {
        "-M_8lcU867sUGWM7arRZ" : {
          "stData1" : "Xtra",
          "stData2" : "8:May:2021",
          "stData3" : "xx",
          "stData4" : "2000"
        }
      },
      "May:2021IncomeBudget" : {
        "Account" : {
          "stData1" : "May:2021",
          "stData2" : "Income",
          "stData3" : "Account",
          "stData4" : "10000"
        }
      },
      "May:2021IncomeEntryAccount" : {
        "-M_2U--kysuCoNayoZji" : {
          "stData1" : "Account",
          "stData2" : "7 May 2021",
          "stData3" : "salary",
          "stData4" : "5000"
        },
        "-M_6vZqyMnElnAKaSy1x" : {
          "stData1" : "Account",
          "stData2" : "7:May:2021",
          "stData3" : "tip",
          "stData4" : "100"
        },
        "-M_7CM5ufcg6Aj1g0E-e" : {
          "stData1" : "Account",
          "stData2" : "8:May:2021",
          "stData3" : "b/d",
          "stData4" : "500"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the xml file of activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/sky"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/idTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/navy"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idBudgetB"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/wait"
                android:textColor="@color/neon"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idAmountB"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/wait"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/neon"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idBalanceB"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="@string/wait"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="@color/neon"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/idItemA"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/boxborder"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/idHistoryA"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/view"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlegreen"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idCategoryA"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/wait"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idBudgetA"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/wait"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idAmountA"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/wait"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/idBalanceA"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/wait"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/idEntryA"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:text="@string/plus"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@drawable/circlegreen"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>




    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/idRecycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:overScrollMode="never" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/idCreateBudget"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="55dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            android:src="@drawable/pen"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:elevation="6dp"
            app:fabSize="mini"
            app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly in all these lines of code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: sum increasing because ```OnBindViewHolder``` called again and again. Try putting a log inside ```myRef.child(title)``` valueEvent listener and check how many times it called when u scrolls.

Comment: Can u update question sharing your database structure and your layout which u want to show in recyclerView ?